# how to set textcolor defined by an android style as the background color?

Tags: android, android-styles

I am using "@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent" to style a textview. I want to use the color used in textcolor item of this style as another textview's background color but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Within your style file you can add another style section called backgroundColor, set the color you want (or image) , And use it whenever you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyBackgroundColor">        
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_back</item>       
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even create a `<color>` tag in `style.xml` or `color.xml` as shown below, and use it in your app.

`<color name="red">#FF0000</color>`

and in `<TextView>` tag assign `textColor:"@color/red"`